# Compare-Object (powershell) : return a property but don't compare with it

Tags: powershell, properties, compareobject

I am using `Compare-Object` to compare 2 bidimensional arrays issued by `Get-ChildItem`.

I am asking it to compare using the `Name` property using `-Property 'Name'`

This returns a table with the `Name` property and `SideIndicator`.

The problem is that I would like to know not only the name of the file, but also its complete path; if I ask `Compare-Object ... -Property @{ Expression = {"$($_.Directory)\$($_.Name)"} }`, it compares using the path, which is not what I want either (this tool I'm coding will be to sync up 2 folders, so obviously the paths are different, hence getting all the files scored as different).

Please let  me know if you need more details !

Comment: I think you're looking to compare `Compare-Object Name, DirectoryName`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no, this outputs everything as it compares using DirectoryName too

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking then. Perhaps `FullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object) with `-Property`** in order to compare the two input collections by one or more specific property values only, by default the **output objects contain *those properties only***, alongside the `.SideIndicator` property that signals which of the two input collections a given difference came from:

```bash
# Sample input collections.
$c1 = @(Get-Date) # a single-element array containing a [datetime] instance
$c2 = @()         # empty array

# Due to -Property Day, the output object contains only the .Day property value, 
# not the whole date.
# -> [pscustomobject] @{ Day = 21; SideIndicator = '<=' }
Compare-Object -Property Day -ReferenceObject $c1 -DifferenceObject $c2
```

- Note: Only if you *omit* `-Property` - resulting in whole-object comparisons (which with complex objects are typically meaningless) - do you get the whole input objects by default, namely in the `.InputObject` property of the `[pscustomobject]` instances that are emitted.

To instead **pass the *whole original objects* through**, use the **`-PassThru`** switch.

That is, instead of emitting `[pscustomobject]` instances with a `.SideIndicator` property, `-PassThru` causes the input objects *themselves* to be emitted.
However, so that you can still determine which side (input collection) a given object came from, the **original objects are *decorated* with a `.SideIndicator` property**, using PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).

```bash
$c1 = @(Get-Date)
$c2 = @()

# Due to adding -PassThru, the output is now the whole date.
$differingDates = 
  Compare-Object -Property Day -PassThru $c1 $c2

# The original [datetime] instance was returned, decorated with a
# .SideIndicator property.
$differingDates.SideIndicator # -> '<='
```

**Caveats**:

- If you combine `-PassThru` with **`-IncludeEqual`**, it is **invariably only the *LHS* (`-ReferenceObject`) object that is passed through for objects that compare as *equal*** (i.e. whose `.SideIndicator` property contains `==`); that is, if two objects compare equal with respect to the given properties but differ with respect to others, you'll only have access to those other properties from the *LHS* objects.

  ```bash
  # Sample input collections.
  $c1 = @(Get-Date -Year 2023)
  $c2 = @(Get-Date -Year 2022)

  # Compare by *day*, with respect to which the two dates are equal.
  # !! Invariably outputs the *2023* date.
  Compare-Object -Property Day -PassThru -IncludeEqual $c1 $c2
  ```
- The **ETS `.SideIndicator` property** is usually invisible, such as in the output from the example above, but **may situationally unexpectedly surface**, such as when you pass a decorated object to `ConvertTo-Json`
  (pipe to `Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator` to avoid this).<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```bash
  # Sample type with only one property, .Bar
  class Foo { [int] $Bar = 42 }

  # Sample input collections.
  $c1 = @([Foo]::new())
  $c2 = @()

  # !! JSON includes .SideIndicator.
  # !! -> {"Bar":42,"SideIndicator":"<="}
  Compare-Object -PassThru $c1 $c2 |
    ConvertTo-Json -Compress
  ```

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell (Core) 7.2+, `ConvertTo-Json` now automatically and invariably ignores ETS properties of `[string]` and `[datetime]` instances, specifically. See [GitHub issue #5797](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5797) for the original discussion that led to this change.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-PassThru` switch to make `Compare-Object` output the full set of input properties:

```
$firstCollection = 'John','Jane' |ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ID=random;Name=$_} }
$secondCollection = 'Johnny','Jane' |ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ID=random;Name=$_} }

Compare-Object $firstCollection $secondCollection -PassThru -Property Name
```

Yielding an output a la:

```
        ID Name   SideIndicator
        -- ----   -------------
 233208599 Johnny =>
1194415032 John   <=
```

Comment: This would be a great example to add to the `Compare-Object` help documentation.

Comment: Thanks, +1, this is concise, but the details in the following answer are useful to me !